# Calling WNetAddConnection2 from PowerShell

Tags: c#, winapi, powershell, wnet

I am trying to directly call some Win32 API's from a PowerShell script. I managed to make WNetAddConnection work with the code below:

```
$cp = New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
$cpar = New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters

$Code = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Win32Api
{
    public class Net
    {
        [DllImport("mpr.dll", EntryPoint = "WNetAddConnection")]
        public static extern uint Map(string lpRemoteName, string lpPassword, string lpLocalName);
        [DllImport("mpr.dll", EntryPoint = "WNetCancelConnection")]
      public static extern uint Delete(string lpName, byte fForce);     
    }
}
"@

$cp.CompileAssemblyFromSource($cpar, $code)
[Win32Api.Net]::Map("\\REMKOLAPTOP\C$", $null, "W:")
```

Now I would like to do the same [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28VS.85%29.aspx), although I found the proper [declarations for C#](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.wnetaddconnection2) I am unsure how to declare this for usage in PowerShell. So my questions is: what is the proper "translation" and an example of calling the API would be great.

Please note that I do not want to use non api methods like the one below:

```
$net = $(New-Object -Com WScript.Network)
$net.MapNetworkDrive("u:", "\\computer\share")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the following code working on PowerShell 2.0.  Note that I also use one PSCX (http://pscx.codeplex.com) function that just converts a Windows error code into a message.  I also setup the options to do an interactive prompt for username and password.  Commented out script is included that shows how you could do the same using PowerShell's Get-Credential cmdlet.

BTW if you supply the username/password via variables to the function be sure to get the order right, it is password followed by username.  That bit me for 10 minutes until I finally figured out I had the order wrong.  Doh!  One other tidbit, for interop help like this be sure to checkout http://www.pinvoke.net.  Anyway, hope this helps.

```
$WNetAddConnection2WrapperSource = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Win32Api {
    public enum ResourceScope {
        RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 1,
        RESOURCE_GLOBALNET,
        RESOURCE_REMEMBERED,
        RESOURCE_RECENT,
        RESOURCE_CONTEXT
    };

    public enum ResourceType {
        RESOURCETYPE_ANY,
        RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
        RESOURCETYPE_PRINT,
        RESOURCETYPE_RESERVED = 8
    };

    [Flags]
    public enum ResourceUsage {
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_NOLOCALDEVICE = 0x00000004,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_SIBLING = 0x00000008,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED = 0x00000010,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_ALL = (RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE | 
                             RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER | RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED),
    };

    public enum ResourceDisplayType {
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NETWORK,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_ROOT,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHAREADMIN,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DIRECTORY,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_TREE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NDSCONTAINER
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class NetResource {
        public ResourceScope Scope;
        public ResourceType Type;
        public ResourceDisplayType DisplayType;
        public ResourceUsage Usage;
        public string LocalName;
        public string RemoteName;
        public string Comment;
        public string Provider;
    };

    [Flags]
    public enum AddConnectionOptions {
        CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001,
        CONNECT_UPDATE_RECENT  = 0x00000002,
        CONNECT_TEMPORARY      = 0x00000004,
        CONNECT_INTERACTIVE    = 0x00000008,
        CONNECT_PROMPT         = 0x00000010,
        CONNECT_NEED_DRIVE     = 0x00000020,
        CONNECT_REFCOUNT       = 0x00000040,
        CONNECT_REDIRECT       = 0x00000080,
        CONNECT_LOCALDRIVE     = 0x00000100,
        CONNECT_CURRENT_MEDIA  = 0x00000200,
        CONNECT_DEFERRED       = 0x00000400,
        CONNECT_RESERVED       = unchecked((int)0xFF000000),
        CONNECT_COMMANDLINE    = 0x00000800,
        CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED   = 0x00001000,
        CONNECT_CRED_RESET     = 0x00002000
    }

    public static class NativeMethods {
        [DllImport("mpr.dll",  EntryPoint="WNetAddConnection2")]    
        public static extern int WNetAddConnection2(
            NetResource netResource, string password, 
            string username, AddConnectionOptions options);
    }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $WNetAddConnection2WrapperSource

$netResource = new-object Win32Api.NetResource
$netResource.Type = [Win32Api.ResourceType]::RESOURCETYPE_DISK
$netResource.LocalName = 'P:'
$netResource.RemoteName = '\\AnotherPC\C'

# Get username and password
#$cred = Get-Credential
#$username = $cred.UserName
#$bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($cred.Password)
#$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
#[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)

$opts = [Win32Api.AddConnectionOptions]::CONNECT_INTERACTIVE -bor
        [Win32Api.AddConnectionOptions]::CONNECT_PROMPT -bor
        [Win32Api.AddConnectionOptions]::CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE

$res = [Win32Api.NativeMethods]::WNetAddConnection2($netResource, 0, 0, $opts)
if ($res -ne 0) {
    # This function comes with PSCX http://pscx.codeplex.com
    Get-ExceptionForWin32 $res  
    throw "Failed to connect"
}
# Display results
net use
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors in PS1.0, however it doesn't work yet. The script seems to wait indefinitely. Compared to my code I miss the CompileAssemblyFromSource($cpar, $code) so I will try to adapt it and see if it works then. Marked your solution as helpfull for now.

Comment: The code works in PS2.0, please note that this:
$res = [Win32Api.NativeMethods]::WNetAddConnection2($netResource, $null, $null, $opts) does NOT work
where this works:
$res = [Win32Api.NativeMethods]::WNetAddConnection2($netResource, 0, 0, $opts)

Comment: I'm glad that worked for ya. Took me a  little while on the stupid signature. I just *ass*umed it was username followed by password.